# Как вывести обратный отсчёт на Swift

Tags: swift, таймер

Возникла задача - выводить на кнопке UIButton таймер обратного отсчёта.

У меня есть DispatchQueue, который стопорит работу кнопки. Но я никак не могу написать блок кода, который будет выводить обратный отсчёт условных 2 часов.

Прошу помощи.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот есть например вариант:

```
@IBOutlet var countDownLabel: UILabel!

var count = 300

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    var timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1.0, target: self, selector: Selector("update"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}

func update() {

    if(count > 0){
        let minutes = String(count / 60)
        let seconds = String(count % 60)
        countDownLabel.text = minutes + ":" + seconds
        count--
    }

}
```

он как вы могли понять выводит в label текст. [Вот здесь туториал](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/articles/117/the-ultimate-guide-to-timer) где хорошо описаны разные способы работы с NSTimer

Comment: Прекрасно, спасибо огромное. Не знал о существовании NSTimer и костылил как попало. Буду изучать дальше. Благодарю!